# Obtener la dirección mac que estoy usando para conectarme a internet en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, macos

Estoy usando [macaddress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macaddress) , pero no sé cómo obtener la dirección MAC  de la interfaz que estoy usando para conectarme a internet.

```
const macaddress = require('macaddress');

macaddress.all(function (err, all) {
  console.log("Your mac address is -->" + JSON.stringify(all, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: Te refieres a la mac de tu router?

Comment: A la mac de mi pc, pero la mac de la interfaz que este conectada a internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El paquete **[network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/network)**
 te puede servir:

> Devuelve la IP, la dirección MAC y el tipo de interfaz para la interfaz de red activa. En OS X y Linux también obtiene la IP de su puerta de enlace asignada.

```
network.get_active_interface(function(err, obj) {

  /* objeto resultante:

  { name: 'eth0',
    ip_address: '10.0.1.3',
    mac_address: '56:e5:f9:e4:38:1d',
    type: 'Wired',
    netmask: '255.255.255.0',
    gateway_ip: '10.0.1.1' }

  */

})
```